# Is it possible to debug tensorflow graph execution in visual fashion?

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, pycharm

Is it possible to debug tensorflow graph execution in visual fashion? For example, in some IDE, like PtCharm?

They have debugger named tfdbg https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger, can I use it in conjunction with PyCharm?

Comment: As far as I understand, since the tensorflow debugger is a very specialized tool, you'd need a specific plugin for your IDE as well. I'm not aware of any.